# Start nginx after reboot automatically

Tags: server, cron, nginx

I am using crontab to start some services after a reboot.

Here is my current crontab:

```
@reboot root /etc/init.d/nginx reload
@reboot /usr/local/bin/forever start /var/www/rtc/index.js
```

It works for `forever`, but nginx never starts.

I also tried:

```
@reboot /etc/init.d/nginx reload
@reboot sudo service nginx reload
```

Any ideas?

My nginx conf looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name www.example.com;

        ssl_certificate /var/wwwssl/example.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /var/wwwssl/example.key.pem;

        location / {
                proxy_pass https://www.example.com:8443;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

**EDIT:**

This solution also did not work

Do that with a systemd drop-in:

```
[Service]
Restart=always
```

which you place as the file `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/override.conf` (creating the directory if it doesn't exist). You can also use `systemctl edit nginx` to create the file.

**EDIT:**

The service is enabled.

```
# systemctl is-enabled nginx
enabled
```

I still have no clue why nginx does not start.

After every `shutdown -r` (I use this to test reboot) I check with `sudo service --status-all` and nginx is not running.

**EDIT**

The syslogs show some errors for nginx after reboot:

```
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "www.example.com" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:100
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

**EDIT:**

Tried to add a resolver:

```
resolver IP valid=30s;
```

Still the same issue

**EDIT**

It may be that nginx cant start after reboot, because of the start order?
Nginx must be started by root. The node app is started by nodeuser with crontab.

Manually it works:

1. I reboot the server
2. After reboot the node app is running (crontab starts the forever process)
3. Nginx has errors
4. I start nginx with `service nginx restart`

I assume what leads to the problem is:

**After reboot the root process is handled first. Nginx tries to start, but the node app is not started yet, so it bugs out. But how would I fix that?**

I seems order makes no difference. I removed the forever start and after reboot the same errors show up.

nginx -t:

[image]

Comment: Why you need to start these service by cron? Doesn't `sudo systemctl enable service.name` work?

Comment: @pa4080 Sadly it also did not work.

Comment: The problem is probably related to the error, try to google it. You can also insert here picture of you Nginx configuration file.

Comment: @JohnRonald I added the config. I also googled the issues, trying every fix I find atm. adding a resolver was a possible fix, but did nothing for me.

Comment: Well, does the server www.example.com exist ? (In your LAN)

Comment: So you cannot start Nginx even when the system is already running ?

Comment: @JohnRonald I can. I just confirmed the problem. The forever process must be started first, otherwise nginx has a problem

Comment: What do you mean by "Forever process" ?

Comment: My node app is started by forever: https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Comment: Also it seems order is not an issue. I have removed the crontab and rebooted the server. Nginx was still down. It only starts if I manually type in service nginx reboot. I have no clue...

Comment: Do not use crontab for this, it too complicated for this. Use systemctl enable nginx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109726/discussion-between-john-ronald-and-roman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is also explained in [this stack topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/940275/nginx-does-not-start-host-not-found)

I had to replace the domain in `proxy_pass` in the nginx config with the IP:

```
proxy_pass https://<IP-OF-YOUR-SERVER>:8443;
```

Answer (score 2):

Roman:

```
sudo systemctl enable nginx
```

Can you try with this command to set link to init as SysV?

```
update-rc.d nginx defaults
```

Why set nginx defaults?

```
When  run  with  the  defaults  option,  update-rc.d  makes links named
       /etc/rcrunlevel.d/[SK]NNname that point to the script /etc/init.d/name,
       using  runlevel  and  dependency information from the init.d script LSB
       comment header.
```

Comment: This also did not help.